# What is the best armour in A Dark Room?

Tags: a-dark-room

What is the best armour in *A Dark Room?* I am saying this because I have got steel armour and is it the best? I have tried to get more steel swords and go far from my village, but, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

Looking at the wiki for this game, the only effect of the various armours is to change your character's HP value as follows:

```
nothing  10
leather  15
iron     25
steel    40
```

That would make steel armour strictly better than all other options.
I do not know whether this stacks with the *gastronome* perk.